# Setting the correct height on a spark datagrid containing variable row heights

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex-spark

While converting a mx:AdvanceDataGrid to a s:DataGrid, my variable row heights caused the height of my DataGrid to be calculated incorrectly.  I am attempting to show all rows without using a scrollbar.

This image shows the incorrect height (the last row is cut off):

[image]

The issue occurs when a row increases in size, to accommodate word wrap for example, causing the row to not be the same size as the typicalItem.  When my project was utilizing the mx:AdvanceDataGrid we worked around this issue by using the measureHeightOfItems() method outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889005 using this code:

```
private function calculateTableHeight():void
{
    var tableHeightPixelHack:Number = 30;
    var numRows:Number = dataGrid.dataProvider != null ? dataGrid.dataProvider.length : 0;
    tableHeight = dataGrid.measureHeightOfItems(-1, numRows) + tableHeightPixelHack;
}
```

My question is, how can I achieve the same result in a s:DataGrid as I did using the measureHeightOfItems method on the mx:AdvanceDataGrid?

**s:DataGrid Component**

```
<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid"
            width="100%"
            columns="{hostComponent.columns}"
            dataProvider="{hostComponent.data}"
            selectionMode="singleRow"
            sortableColumns="false"
            styleName="goalsDataGrid"
            variableRowHeight="true"
            verticalScrollPolicy="off"
            horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
            doubleClickEnabled="true"
/>
```

**Custom Item Renderer (assigned through code)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer   xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                      focusEnabled="true">

    <s:Rect top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0" z="-1"> 
        <s:fill> 
            <s:SolidColor color="{data.rowColor}"/> 
        </s:fill> 
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Label id="lblData"
             styleName="tableRow"
             text="{label}"
             width="100%"
             height="100%"
             maxDisplayedLines="-1"
             lineBreak="toFit" />        
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: If you want all the rows to be displayed then give 100% height in the datagrid. It will adjust as per the row heights.

Comment: @Sumit I just double checked, and I notice no differences in the DataGrid while omitting or including `height="100%"` in my mxml.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Set verticalScrollPolicy="auto" in your DataGrid

Comment: I am attempting to show all rows at once without a scroll bar.  I have updated my post to include that info.  Thanks,

Comment: What container you are using for the datagrid. Can you post your container code as well?

Answer (score 0):

For **Spark** `DataGrid` you can calculate the height of the `DataGrid` as below:

```
private function calculateTableHeight():void
    {
        var totalHeight:Number = 0;
        for (var row:int = 0; row < dataGrid.dataProvider.length; row++) {
            var renderer:IGridItemRenderer = dataGrid.grid.getItemRendererAt(row,1);
            if (renderer){
                totalHeight += renderer.height;
            }
        }
        dataGrid.height = totalHeight + dataGrid.columnHeaderGroup.height + 2;
    }
```

Here is an example app:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           updateComplete="sizeDGExactly()"
           width="100%"
           height="100%">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import spark.components.gridClasses.IGridItemRenderer;

    [Bindable]
    private var notes:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {who: 'Bikram', note_txt: 'ActionScript 3 has empowered Flash developers with faster code execution and a ton of API enhancements.Last line.'},
        {who: 'Anup', note_txt: 'Unfortunately, it has also led to the need for a much higher level of developer responsibility than ever before. ' +
        'In order to prepare and educate developers on how to deal with some of this new responsibility, \n\nI am writing a series of articles on resource ' +
        'management in AS3, Flex 2, and Flash 9. \n\nThe first of these articles discussed the mechanics of the Garbage Collector in Flash Player 9. ' +
        'This article will focus on the implications some of the new features of AS3 have on resource management, and the potential headaches they could ' +
        'cause you even in simple projects. \n\nThe next article in the series will introduce some of the new tools we have at our disposal to deal with these issues.Last line.'},
        {who: 'Mark', note_txt: 'The biggest change in AS3 that affects resource management is the new display list model. In Flash Player 8 and below, ' +
        'when a display object was removed from the screen (with removeMovie or unloadMovie), it and all of its descendants were immediately removed from ' +
        'memory, and halted all code execution.Last line.'},
        {who: 'George', note_txt: 'It is very important to note that not only will the display object continue to use memory, it will also continue to ' +
        'execute any “idle” code, such as Timers, enterFrames, and listeners outside its scope. A couple of examples may help illustrate this issue:'+
        'You have a game sprite that subscribes to its own enterFrame event. Every frame it moves and carries out some calculations to determine ' +
        'it’s proximity to other game elements. In AS3, even after you remove it from the display list and null all references to it, it will continue ' +
        'to run that code every frame until it is removed by garbage collection. You must remember to explicitly remove the enterFrame listener when the sprite ' +
        'is removed.\n\n'+
        'Consider a MovieClip that follows the mouse by subscribing to the stage’s mouseMove event (which is the only way to achieve this effect in ' +
        'the new event model). Unless you remember to remove the listener, the clip will continue to execute code every time the mouse is moved, even after ' +
        'the clip is “deleted”. By default, the clip will execute forever, as a reference to it exists from the stage for event dispatch (we will look at ' +
        'how to avoid this in the next article).\n\n'+
        'Now imagine the implications of instantiating and removing a bunch of sprites before the GC does a sweep, or if you failed to remove all references. ' +
        'You could inadvertently max out the CPU fairly easily, slowing your application or game to a crawl, or even stalling the users’ computers entirely. ' +
        'There is NO WAY to force the Flash Player to kill a display object and stop it executing. You must do this manually when it is removed from the display. ' +
        'I will examine strategies to manage this task in a future article.\n\n'+
        'Here\’s a simple example (Flash Player 9 required). Click the “create” button to create a new Sprite instance. The sprite instance will start ' +
        'outputting a counter. Click remove and note how the output continues, despite the fact that all references to the sprite have been nulled. You can create ' +
        'multiple instances to see how this issue compounds over the life of an application. Source code is available at the end of this article. Last line.'}
    ]);

    private function sizeDGExactly():void
    {
        if (notesDataGrid)
        {
            var totalHeight:Number = 0;
            for (var row:int = 0; row < notesDataGrid.dataProvider.length; row++) {
                var renderer:IGridItemRenderer = notesDataGrid.grid.getItemRendererAt(row,1);
                if (renderer){
                    totalHeight += renderer.height;
                }
            }
            notesDataGrid.height = totalHeight + notesDataGrid.columnHeaderGroup.height + 2;
        }
    }

    public function onDeleteButtonClick(item:Object):void
    {
        notes.removeItemAt(notes.getItemIndex(item));
        sizeDGExactly();
    }

    ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%"
                left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10"
                horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Group width="100%">
                <s:Panel title="Empty Top Panel" width="50%" horizontalCenter="0">
                    <s:Label text="This is just an additional component in the layout." width="100%"/>
                </s:Panel>
            </s:Group >
            <s:HGroup width="100%">

            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup width="100%">

                <s:DataGrid id="notesDataGrid"
                            verticalCenter="0"
                            width="100%"
                            dataProvider="{notes}"
                            sortableColumns="false"
                            variableRowHeight="true">
                    <s:columns>
                        <s:ArrayList>
                            <s:GridColumn width="200"
                                          headerText="Who Noted"
                                          dataField="who"/>
                            <s:GridColumn dataField="note_txt"
                                          headerText="Note">
                                <s:itemRenderer>
                                    <fx:Component>
                                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                            <s:Label width="100%" height="100%" text="{data.note_txt}"
                                                     paddingTop="10"
                                                     paddingBottom="10"
                                                     paddingLeft="10"
                                                     paddingRight="10"/>
                                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                                    </fx:Component>
                                </s:itemRenderer>
                            </s:GridColumn>
                            <s:GridColumn width="70">
                                <s:itemRenderer>
                                    <fx:Component>
                                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                            <s:Button width="60" height="20" label="Delete"
                                                      horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
                                                     click="outerDocument.onDeleteButtonClick(data)"/>
                                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                                    </fx:Component>
                                </s:itemRenderer>
                            </s:GridColumn>
                        </s:ArrayList>
                    </s:columns>
                </s:DataGrid>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:Group width="100%">
                <s:Panel title="Empty Bottom Panel" width="50%" horizontalCenter="0">
                    <s:Label text="This is just an additional component in the layout." width="100%"/>
                </s:Panel>
            </s:Group>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

[image]